# set video as background using css

Tags: html, css

I want to set video as background for particular div and need to show scrollbar id needed for the page content text and icon wants to display over the background video.
now video display in the corner of  right bottom.

```css
.contentContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content__heading {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 44px;
}

.content__teaser {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.content__cta {
  display: inline-block;
 
  padding: 12px 48px;
  color: #ff3c64;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 4px #ff3c64;
}

.video {
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1;
   width: auto;
  height: auto;
 top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  min-width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="sample" style="min-height:100px;background-color:blue;">
 sdadjsa gsahd sadgh asgd
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 box">
   <h4></h4>
   <div class="contentContainer">
      <div class="content__heading">
    headeing dsfgds sdfhjsd sd dsfgsdfg dgfgjg
   </div>
   <div class="content__teaser">
        <img src="sample.jpg" alt="demo">
   </div> 
   </div>
   <video loop  autoplay preload="none" class="video" ><source src="http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```css
.contentContainer {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 720px;
 text-align: center;
}
.content__heading {
 margin-bottom: 24px;
 text-align:center;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 44px;
}
.content__teaser {
 margin-bottom: 24px;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 22px;
}
.content__cta {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 12px 48px;
 color: #ff3c64;
 font-size: 22px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: solid 4px #ff3c64;
}
.video {
  width: 100%;

}
.box{ position:absolute;}
```

```html
<div class="sample" style="min-height:100px;background-color:blue;"> sdadjsa gsahd sadgh asgd </div>
<div class="col-md-4 box">
    <h4></h4>
    <div class="contentContainer">
       <div class="content__heading"> headeing dsfgds sdfhjsd sd dsfgsdfg dgfgjg </div>
       <div class="content__teaser"> <img src="sample.jpg" alt="demo"> </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<video loop  autoplay preload="none" class="video" >
   <source src="http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   
 </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.contentContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content__heading {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #272727;
  font-size: 44px;
}

.content__teaser {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.content__cta {
  display: inline-block;
 
  padding: 12px 48px;
  color: #ff3c64;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 4px #ff3c64;
}

.video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background-size: cover;
 transition: 1s opacity; 
}
```

```html
<div class="sample" style="min-height:100px;background-color:blue;">
 sdadjsa gsahd sadgh asgd
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 box">
   <h4></h4>
   <div class="contentContainer">
      <div class="content__heading">
    headeing dsfgds sdfhjsd sd dsfgsdfg dgfgjg
   </div>
   <div class="content__teaser">
        <img src="sample.jpg" alt="demo">
   </div> 
   </div>
   <video loop  autoplay preload="none" class="video" ><source src="http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.homepage-hero-module {
 border-right: none;
 border-left: none;
 position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
 display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
position: relative;
bottom: 0%;
left: 0%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
z-index: 100;
position: absolute;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
width: 100%;
}
.video-container .title-container {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}
.video-container .description .inner {
font-size: 1em;
width: 45%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container .link {
position: absolute;
bottom: 3em;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1001;
font-size: 2em;
color: #fff;
}
 .video-container .link a {
 color: #fff;
}
 .video-container video {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 }
 .video-container video.fillWidth {
 width: 100%;
 }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bosspetta/wokoyytv/)